# Problems on POST REQUEST HttpURLConnection Android 4.0+

Tags: android, post, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, httpurlconnection

I'm having some trouble making a simple HTTP POST request on a website. It seems like the POST parameters is not being sent!
Scenario: 

HTTP Response code 200 - Wrong User/Pass - Occurring on Android 4.0+

HTTP Response code 302 - User/Pass OK - Occurring on others SDK versions

The Web form thats works OK:

```
<form id="form_mn_login" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="http://dummyhost/r.php" class="estil" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
<input type="text" name="m_email" id="m_email" />
<input type="password" name="m_senha" id="m_senha" />
```

The code (inside doInBackground AsyncTask's method):

```
urlParameters = "m_email="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&m_senha="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            // Create connection
            url = new URL("http://dummyhost/r.php");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            // Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            publishProgress(30);


            Log.w("responsecode", Integer.toString(connection.getResponseCode()));
```

This issue only shows up when I emulate it on Android 4.0+ AVD Devices. (Tried on 2.2,2.3.3, 3.0 and it works flawlessly)
What am I missing?

I'm aware maybe this is an server issue, but I really believe there must be an workaround for this. I've tried thousands of different ways of doing it but none seems to work as it should.

Thanks a lot,
RC